# Google Drive permissions are not getting trickled down to children

Tags: google-drive-api

**Google drive permissions not getting trickled down.**

Suppose I have a folder(Folder1) with 2 files(File1 , File2) inside it. Then I share the Folder1 with 2 users (user1 , user2) . The files are getting permission of the folder(Folder1).

Now I remove one user(say user1) from file File1 which is inside Folder1.

Now I create a second folder(Folder2). I add this folder as File1's parent.
Then I add the user1 to Folder2.

Ideally parent's permission are transferred down to their children files/folders. **Then why the File1 after getting referenced to Folder2, doesn't get its new parent permissions.** If I add a new user to Folder2 , he gets access to File1. Then why din't the permissions trickle down priorly.

Every operation is done using **google drive api v2**.

Comment: Because that's not how the API works.  You need to update them.